# Error: java: Illegal char<:>

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, intellij-idea

estou tendo esse erro Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http:\api.jquery.com

Sei que erro está na sentença, só que eu não encontro isso em nenhum lugar para corrigir. Procurei linha a linha e não tenho ideia de onde esteja. E código agora ta relativamente grande. To usando SpringBoot e to com diversas paginas html. Alguém tem alguma ideia para me ajudar?

A main

```
package ProjetoRua.com.projetorua;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

DB

```
package ProjetoRua.com.projetorua;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; 
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

 @Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DataConfiguration {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:63342/projetorua");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("123456");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
    return adapter;
    }
}
```

O resto é página html. Pode ser que esteja nelas mas eu olhei tudo kk

[image: Console]

[image: box de pequisa]

Comment: falta uma `/` do http na sua URL, onde você chama esse link? Corriga para: `http://api.jquey.com`

Comment: Sim sim, o problema é que não sei onde está essa URL. Procurei linha a linha mas não acho

Comment: Pressiona duas vezes `Shift`, a [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html) deve abrir um box de procura. Ve se acha sua URL por ali. Outra coisa, clicando duas vezes em cima do erro, ele não te encaminha para o local onde o catch aconteceu?

Comment: Estou usando intellij, só por observação mesmo kk. Clicando duas vezes não abre nada, e o box de procura não achou nada.

Comment: Por isso to achando estranho, o erro é fácil de resolver, mas não consigo achar onde está

Answer (score 0):

Este é o problema do IDEA - não do seu projeto.

A maneira mais fácil de resolvê-lo é fazer o seguinte:
No painel superior do IDEA *-> Arquivo -> Estrutura do Projeto (**Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S**) -> Bibliotecas Globais -> "**Excluir***" para a biblioteca "`Juqery`"

Em algum motivo, quando "`api.jquery`" é incluído como Biblioteca Global - isso causará esse erro.